# How to launch python script from mpv/lua

Tags: python, lua, mpv

I have written an mpv script in python using

https://github.com/iwalton3/python-mpv-jsonipc

I'm now trying to launch the script when mpv opens but cant seem to get it to launch I tried running from mpv with

> mp.command("run", "python3", "D:\TingTingin\pycharmprojects\mpvipc\got launched.py")

and lua

> os.execute("D:\TingTingin\pycharmprojects\mpvipc\got launched.py")

but the script doesn't run im not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: Backslashes must be escaped inside double-quoted string literals.

Comment: thanks by using `mp.commandv("run", "python3", [[D:\TingTingin\pycharmprojects\mpvipc\got lanched.py]])` it seems to work need to put it inside [[]] also had to use commandv instead of command

Answer (score 1):

> Backslashes must be escaped inside double-quoted string literals.
> Egor Skriptunoff

Using `mp.commandv("run", "python3", [[D:\TingTingin\pycharmprojects\mpvipc\got launched.py]])` it seems to work need to put it inside [[]] also had to use commandv instead of command thanks to Egor Skriptunoff

Answer (score 0):

I don't think scripts are automatically enabled, unless you specify during startup.

from `mpv --list-options`:

```
--script                         alias for --scripts-append (CLI/config files only)
--script-opts                    Key/value list (default: )
  --script-opts-add
  --script-opts-append
  --script-opts-set
  --script-opts-remove
--scripts                        String list (default: ) [file]
  --scripts-add
  --scripts-append
  --scripts-clr
  --scripts-del
  --scripts-pre
  --scripts-set
  --scripts-toggle
  --scripts-remove
```

Possibly use a GUI that allows you to permanently set startup-options that way, such as [SMPlayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPlayer).

Be easy enough to alias your mpv command in `.bash-aliases` but I'm guessing you're on Windows because of the directory name...

```
alias mpv="mpv --script '/home/sketch2/Programming/Scripts/launched.py'"
```

a TSR that looks for launching, such as [Devilspie2](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/devilspie2/) would do it.  Generally used for resizing and putting apps in locations you like.  Something like that could be programmed to auto-run your mpv script.  That might be Linux only, so you'd have to hunt for something similar in (assuming) Windows.  Maybe it runs through their Linux-subsystem, I don't know.  Doubt it, probably polls X in ways that windows wouldn't expect.

Are you gonna use it all the time, or just once in a while?  Can you just have your script running in the background, and have it check for a running instance of mpv every 30 seconds or so?  That's essentially what a [TSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_and_stay_resident_program) does.

https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/User-Scripts

---

**Edit:**

I just realized there's an `mpv.conf` -- that's where you'd set it.
I don't know where it's stored on Windows, but on *nix it's in `~/.config/mpv/`

Literally just commandline-parameters followed with what you set them to.  Comments are #hashed out.

https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/etc/mpv.conf